# php-fpm with NGINX response time exponentially increase over time

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, cpu-usage, iops

I have a load balanced application on AWS, on two c4.2xlarge (8 vCPUs, 15GB ram) servers and they serve a very simplistic site but with a system call to ffmpeg encode a <5s mp4. Individually, the script takes < 1s to execute, but under stress, the response time goes over the roof.

500 concurrent users over a period of 20s

[image: load-test-1]

Testing with 1000 concurrent users over the span of 1 minute gets a lot worse, regardless of the load balance setup.

[image]

I cannot figure out why the response time of the request increases quite significantly over the duration of my stress tests.

## fpm pool configuration

```
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 25
pm.min_spare_servers = 25
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 500

request_terminate_timeout = 180s

php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 3M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 3M
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 180
```

## nginx configuration

```
events {
    worker_connections 66536;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

...

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180; 
}
```

The duration of the request to be completed is not a particular issue in my case, as long as is more or less consistent and < 15s.

So, can't help but wonder, where am I going wrong about my approach and what should I look into, in order to solve this increasing response time?

**Update**

I have now, changed to io1 with 2000 iops for a 40gb root block device (don't really need EBS)

Some server stats, with peeks of when I ran the tests

CPU 1 minute interval 
[image: cpu-utilization-1minute]

CPU 5 minutes interval 
[image: cpu-utilization-5minutes]

Really strange how it peeks to 100% in the 1 minute interval

**Update2**

Command and its arguments

```
ffmpeg -r 7 -s 470x264 -i upload/1494515054/%01d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast test/`date +%s`.mp4
```

Execution times: ranging from 0m0.148s to 0m0.163s

Howeve, the command is executed via php's `shell_exec`, and in that script it rounds around 350ms 500ms

Comment: You didn't show any information about your host resource usage - CPU, Disk, memory utilization

Comment: Just updated with some stats

Comment: Could you provide some benchmark for encoding script? But in general encoding is CPU bound and if the script takes 0.5 seconds to complete you won't be able to serve more than 2 *8 / 0.5 = 32 requests per second and you are hitting servers with hundreds of requests so obviously your response time skyrockets.

Comment: Added some more stats... (where does the 2 come from?)

Comment: You said that you have 2 load balanced servers.

Comment: Right, yes... got confused for a second.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might just be the disk I/O; 1000 concurrent users over the span of 1 minute ~ 16.7/second, presumably each accessing a different mp4 file that you have to encode. How long does it take you to encode 1000 different mp4 files simultaneously (or if you can schedule it, spawning 17 new encoding tasks every second), and what is the disk I/O like?

Comment: interesting idea. Will try and run that encoding for 1000 mp4s